# How to find an element using text through Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have the following html:

```
<p class="k-reset"><a class="k-icon k-i-expand" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a>Unit: QA Room: 1</p>
```

I can't seem to get valid syntax to click on this element.  I've tried the following:

```
IWebElement webElement5 = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='k-icon k-i-expand']"));
webElement5.Click();
```

```
IWebElement webElement5 = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[text(), 'Unit: QA Room: 1']"));
webElement5.Click();
```

When I try to use the text(), I get an error stating that it is not a valid XPath expression.  Everywhere I look on the internet uses that syntax.  I'm very new to c#/Selenium/XPath values.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: The syntax is not correct. If you want text equals then you want `//p[.='Unit: QA Room: 1']`. If you want text contains then you want `//p[contains(., 'Unit: QA Room: 1')]`. You seem to be mixing the two... replace the `,` with a `=` and it should be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed partial syntax of `contains`

```
"//p[contains(text(), 'Unit: QA Room: 1')]"
```

For direct match use `=`

```
"//p[text()='Unit: QA Room: 1']"
```

Comment: **Do note** that `//p[text(), 'Unit: QA Room: 1']` **is valid XPath 2.0**. This will select every `p` element because the truth value of a sequence is false only when it's empty.

Comment: @Alejandro The browsers support by default `xpath 1.0`, you can test it in dev tools, therefor so is Selenium. That's why the OP got invalid syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you can use either of the following solution:

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.CssSelector("p.k-reset>a.k-icon.k-i-expand")).Click();
  ```
- *XPath 1*:

  ```
  Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='k-reset']/a[@class='k-icon k-i-expand']")).Click();
  ```
- *XPath 2*:

  ```
  Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='k-reset' and normalize-space()='Unit: QA Room: 1']")).Click();
  ```